# Implementing each in vanila JS similar to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I have implemented `each` function like this in JS:

```
Object.prototype.each = function(fn){
  for (var x in this){
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(x)){
        fn(x);
    }
  }
  return this;
};


var o = {'a' : 'apple', 'b' : 'bat', 'c' : 'cat'};
o.each(function(i){
   alert(i);
});
```

Though this works fine. Is there anything wrong in it. Asking because I am learning JS.

Also why does it produces error if I do:

```
{'a' : 'apple', 'b' : 'bat', 'c' : 'cat'}.each(function(i){
   alert(i);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around the object or it will interpret it as a block due to the opening and closing curly brackets.

```
({'a' : 'apple', 'b' : 'bat', 'c' : 'cat'}).each(function(i){
   alert(i);
});
```

When you do it without the parentheses, the interpreter will "see" this:

```
{ // open block statement
   'a' : 'apple', 'b' : 'bat', 'c' : 'cat' // not a valid expression!
}.each(function(i){ // there's no dot property access notation for statements!
   alert(i);
});
```

Which is a **block** with a single expression. However, since that is not a valid expression it will return a syntax error. Even if it were a valid expression, it would still give you an error since blocks do not have properties and therefore the dot property access notation is not applicable:

```
{ console.log("hello world"); }.each(function(){})
```

Thus, you need to tell the interpreter that the object is an expression by wrapping it in parentheses to remove the ambiguity (since you cannot put a statement inside a parentheses - only expressions).

Comment: Is my each implemeation OK by the way or anything wrong with it?

Comment: @Dev555 I think it might be a bit more useful if you did: `fn.call(this, x, this[x])` instead of just `fn(x)`. Otherwise, I don't see anything obviously wrong with it.

Comment: @Dev555 You should also read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty so you can learn how to define non-enumerable properties so your method doesn't end up in `for in` loops.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation looks good.

`{'a' : 'apple', 'b' : 'bat', 'c' : 'cat'}.each...` produces error because it is syntactically incorrect. Enclose is inside `()` it will work.

Try this.

```
({'a' : 'apple', 'b' : 'bat', 'c' : 'cat'}).each(function(i){
   alert(i);
});
```

Comment: I noticed that too, but can you explain why it is syntactly incorrect?

Comment: Because when there are opening and closing cur brackets, JavaScript engine treats it as a block and you cannot call a method on a script block. `function(){}.something()` will not work in the same way. But `(function(){}).something()` will work.